# Why translating next.js page not work as expected after getStaticProps invalidation?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

Quick summary:

- I'm trying to use i18n with Next.js and translate my category page.
- I'm using the `getStaticProps` function in order to translate my page and fetch data from DB.
- **The expected result:** Fetch data from db, if the data has changed after 10 seconds then revalidate and show the page with the initial translation.
- **The actual results:** I'm fetching the page for the first time and the data is displayed and the translation is ok, I'm changing something from DB and waiting 10 seconds. The data is changed correctly but the translation is not working (I can see the translation keys instead of the actual words e.g 'share_btn' instead 'Share' text).

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  try {
    await connect(); // My DB connection
    const files = await File.find({ category: 'some category', approved: true });

    return {
      props: {
        files: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(files)),
        error: false,
        ...(await serverSideTranslations(
          context.locale,
          ['category', 'home'],
          i18nConfig
        )),
      },
      revalidate: 10,
    };
  } catch (e) {
    return {
      props: {
        files: [],
        error: true,
        ...(await serverSideTranslations(
          context.locale,
          ['category', 'home'],
          i18nConfig
        )),
      },
      revalidate: 10,
    };
  }
}
```

versions of related technologies:

```
"next": "12.2.3",
"next-i18next": "12.0.1",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
```

I will provide more information if needed.
Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next#reloading-resources-in-development ?

Comment: @adrai this is still not working for me. After changing something in DB and refreshing the page the item is appear but the translation is not reloaded (showing only the translation keys instead the actual text). Any advice please?

Comment: set debug to true and check the logs